# import.meta.glob how to infer correct module's type in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I tried to use import.meta.glob to infer correct module's type, but I don't know how to achieve it.

This is my director tree.

```
    └─store
        └─reducer
            └─index.ts
            └─userSlice.ts
        └─index.ts
```

// userSlice.ts

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

interface UserState {
  name: string
  phone: number
  userType: number
}

const initialState: UserState = {
  name: 'genz',
  phone: 10101010,
  userType: 1
}

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateUserInfo: (state, action: PayloadAction<UserState>) => {
      return { ...state, ...action.payload }
    }
  }
})

export const { updateUserInfo } = userSlice.actions

export default userSlice.reducer

export type { UserState }
```

// reducer/index.ts

```
import { Reducer } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const reducers: Record<string, Reducer> = {}

const modules: Record<string, { default: Reducer }> = import.meta.glob(
  './*.ts',
  {
    eager: true
  }
)

Object.entries(modules).forEach(([key, module]) => {
  const name: string = /(?<=\.\/).+?(?=Slice\.ts)/.exec(key)?.[0] || ''
  const reducer = module.default

  reducers[name] = reducer
})

export default reducers
```

// store/index.ts

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import reducer from './reducer'
// import userReducer from './reducer/userSlice'

const store = configureStore({
  // reducer: {
  //   user: userReducer
  // }
  reducer
})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch

export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector

export default store
```

When I use the follow code，I can get the correct types, but use import.meta.glob, it didn't work anymore.

```
import userReducer from './reducer/userSlice'

const store = configureStore({
   reducer: {
     user: userReducer
   }
})
```

I would appreciate for your help, thanks.

```
I expected that I can get the correct types or tips.
function App() {
  const userInfo = useAppSelector((state) => state.user)


  return (
    <>
      <div>{userInfo.('name'|'phone'|'userType')}</div>
    <>
  )

}
```

Comment: try to add compilerOptions.types: ["vite/client"] in your tsconfig.json

Comment: I've been tried add this, but it didn't work........@Liap

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issues and could solve it like this

```js
import {configureStore, Reducer, UnknownAction} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {log} from "../utils/tools.ts";
import {TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";

/**
 * Import all slices from the slices folder
 *
 */
const modules = import.meta.glob(
    [
        './slices/**/*.slice.ts'
    ],
    { eager: true },
);

const slices = Object.entries(modules)
    .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
        const sliceName = key.replace('./slices/', '').replace('.slice.ts', '');
        // @ts-expect-error - We know that the value is a module
        acc[sliceName] = (value as Record<string, unknown>).default;
        return acc;
    }, {} as Record<string, Reducer<unknown, UnknownAction>>);

const storeOptions = {
    reducer: slices,
    devTools: true
}

export const store = configureStore(storeOptions);

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch;
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;


export default store
```